# PHP devuelve 1 hora más de la establecida

Tags: php

Estimados tengo la siguiente consulta estoy trabajando en localhost con wamppserver, actualmente en mi pais (Chile) son las **2021-04-18 22:49:16**, pero si yo ejecuto las siguientes lineas en PHP, me devuelve 1 hora más siendo las **2021-04-18 23:49:16**, si ejectuto las mismas lineas de codigo, pero en el servidor web, me devuelve la hora de forma correcta.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $fecha;
```

Adjunto los php.ini de ambos servidores

**Localhost**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Servidor Web**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La zona horaria local del equipo está correcta? Panel de control - Reloj y Región - Fecha y Hora - Cambiar la zona horaria - En la ventana, en la parte de Zona horaria debe estar `(UTC-04:00) Santiago`

Comment: La zona horaria del equipo está correcta, pero aún así devuelve 1 hora mas de la que debería ser

Comment: Intenta crear un objeto y haz debug de él, así podrás ver con qué zona horaria se está creando, por ejemplo: `$mDate=new DateTime();` y luego `var_dump($mDate);`

Comment: Es posible que uno de los dos tenga DST habilitado y el otro no?